# Special Chars to ASCII

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, ascii, special-characters

Using VBA in MS Access, is there a way to have all special chars in a string replaced with the ASCII equivalent?  In other words, I want the ampersands gone and replaced with `&amp;`, along with every other special character.

A PHP equivalent is `HTMLSpecialChars`. I have semi-colons in my inserts that are probably blowing up my query. I need semi-colons converted to clean my text for an insert.

Comment: Ummm, ampersands are perfectly valid ASCII characters, there's nothing special about them.  At least NOT in ASCII.

Comment: I think that what you're really asking for here is something like HTML Entitization?

Comment: A PHP equivalent is HTMLSpecialChars.  I should have been more specific to my problem... I have semi-colons in my inserts that are probably blowing up my query.  I need semi-colons converted to clean my text for an insert.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want semi-colons replaced by something like "&semi;" which means you have to replace ampersand with "&amp;".  For HTML, the special ASCII characters are ampersand, greater than and less than so there are character entities for them.  There is no official character entity for semi-colon.  I would have thought the percentage system (used, for example, in URLs and SMTP) was more suited to your needs.  "%20" = space, "%3A" = semi-colon, "%25" = percent.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Access 2000 the [Replace Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/replace-function-HA001228898.aspx) is available in Access VBA.

```
? Replace("a&v", "&", "&amp;")
a&amp;b
```

You would need to repeat that function pattern for any other characters you want to replace.

However, if this is intended to prevent blowing up an INSERT statement, it may be a red herring.  You should be able to insert text which contains semi-colons or ampersands into a text field as long as the text you insert is properly quoted or is supplied as a parameter to a parameter query.  Both these statements execute successfully for me.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyTable (MyText) " & _
    "VALUES ('a&b')"
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyTable (MyText) " & _
    "VALUES ('a;b')"
```

It may help to show us the SQL for your failing INSERT statement with a simple example of the text which causes it to blow up.  Also tell us the error message, if any.  Please paste the SQL into your question rather than into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.renownedmedia.com/blog/convert-ascii-to-utf-8-using-vba/